# Get Multiple Row Values From Single Column with Multiple Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

```
id   unique_id    name     franchise_id
1    MR1000       aaa      0
2    FR1001       bbb      0
3    GE1003       ccc      0
4    GE1004       ddd      0
5    CL1005       eee      2
```

this is my table i want to fetch record from this table

fetch the 5th record from that find franchise_id 2 search with id and get unique id value too

i need result like this:

```
franchise_id     uniqueid     name
FR1001           CL1005       eee
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, you will always get a better response from this community if you show that you have tried to solve your requirement yourself. So if you have made an attempt to write this query please show your attempt.  How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _So is not where you come to get code written for you_

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self join and an alias so you override the real column's name.

```
select a.unique_id as franchise_id, b.unique_id, b.name
from test as a
left join test as b
on b.franchise_id = a.id
where b.unique_id = 'CL1005'
```

The `as franchise_id` overwrites the real column name and will return it as the new columns name.

The `left join test as b
    on b.franchise_id = a.id` joins the table to itself where the `franchise_id` matches an `id`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb576f/11

All `b` values will be NULL if the `a` column doesn't have a reference. You can change the `join` type from a `left` join to `inner join` if you want to require a match.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e9dad/2

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.franchise_id
              from t t2
              order by id
              limit 4, 1
             );
```